# Unicode escape for @ symbol displays as Chinese character

Tags: css, unicode-escapes

The Unicode character for @ symbol is [40](http://unicode-table.com/en/#control-character) but when I tried it, it just display like chinese character.

```css
p::after{
  content: 'foo\40bar.com';
}
```

```html
<p>Email: </p>
```

Comment: http://www.merttol.com/articles/code/introduction-to-css-escape-sequences.html

Answer (score 5):

Giving a space after unicode character displays the `@` symbol correctly.

```css
p::after{
  content: 'foo\40 bar.com';
  /* give a space ^^ after unicode character */
}
```

```html
<p>Email: </p>
```

Answer (score 2):

From [W3](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-escapes):

> If, on the other hand, the next character is one that can be used in hexadecimal numbers, it won't be clear where the end of the number is. In these cases there are two options. The first is to use a space after the escape.
>
> Alternatively, you can use a 6-digit hexadecimal number, with or without a space.

```css
p::after{
  content: 'foo\000040bar.com';
}
```

```html
<p>Email: </p>
```